# ContextMenuStrip is not DpiAware?

Tags: winforms, .net-core

I have a form with a simple ContextMenuStrip:

[image]

Application is created in VS2022, SDK7, WinForms, with defining PerMonitorV2 Dpi in csproj file.

I have 2 displays (Primary: 100%, other: 175%).

If I launch the app on the primary screen, it works as intended:

[image]

But if I move this window to the 175% screen:

[image]

As you can see, context menu's font is stayed at the original size, i.e. it didn't scaled up to 175%.

Now, if I launch the app on the secondary (175%) screen:

[image]

Labels are scaled, but the tickmark is not.

If I move this window back to the primary (100%):

[image]

ContextMenu's size stays the original, ie. it's not scaling down back to 100%.

Can I somehow overcome on this problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#configuring-your-windows-forms-app-for-high-dpi-support

Comment: I know this page, but there is no relevant information inside for this particular control. I ended up recreating every single time this context menu before opening. -.- Ah, and of course, adding my own tickmark bitmap, as the original one is not being scaled.

Comment: For the checkmark part, select the checkable TS items and set their `ImageScaling` properties to `None` instead of `SizeToFit`.